# JQuery 1.9.1 broke my script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Not sure why, when I link to [jquery 1.9.1](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js) to make one script on my page work this old script fails to function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn-slide").click(function(){
        $("#qlinks-panel").slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Is there anything I can do to update it? Am I off track thinking that it is depreciated code causing the problem?

Comment: More code would help us monitor the issue.

Comment: Can't be true...  none of these are deprecated... See if you can replicate.

Comment: None of the used methods is deprecated or removed in jQuery 1.9, what makes you think that it broke your code? Do you get any errors?

Comment: If `.btn-slide` is dynamic, use `.on('click', '.btn-slide', function`.

Comment: It probably has something to do with `$(".btn-slide")`. Every single className would have to contain `$("#qlinks-panel")` or `$("#qlinks-panel")` will be undefined. Note that `$(this)` refers to `$(".btn-slide")`.

Comment: works fine? => http://jsfiddle.net/b6urA/1/

Answer (score 0):

Please try giving the below code in the page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Also, after including this, watch your console for information on what you need to change to be able to remove the migrate plugin.